# Google Hangout plugin linux ARM (armhf)

Tags: linux, google-talk

I have installed Picuntu Linux (which is based on Ubuntu) on my Minix Neo X5 device but i am having problems installing Google talk plugin (needed for Google Hangout video conf). THe reason i cannot install because device is based on armhf (ARM) architecture and the available plugins are for 32 and 64 bit. Is there any way I can install it to my device?

Answer (score 1):

The only support Google has for ARM Linux is Android and ChromeOS.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Can you update your answer to include a link to a primary source confirming your answer?